# Spurious errors from WatiN with MSTest

Tags: c#, visual-studio, mstest, watin

I'm running MSTest to use the browser-automation framework, WatiN. When I run tests individually they always pass but however when I run the entire set of automation tests 7-8 tend to fail with different errors each time. All the tests are isolated and login to the site from the beginning every time, so I don't think it's related to the way the tests are written.

Has anyone else encountered this?

Is it likely to be MSTest related?

Comment: Which errors do you get?

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that you are not closing the browser at the end of each and every test. This can cause the session from the previous state to still be around when you run the next step. For example, you might still be logged in when your test is expecting a login page.